# 301 redirect from url with suffix to url without suffix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

How would I redirect:
http://www.mydomain.com/dynamicname_fixedsuffix.someimageextension
To:
http://www.mydomain.com/dynamicname.someimageextension
?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_fixedsuffix(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

$1 is whatever comes before the `_fixedsuffix`, and $2 is whatever comes after.

You might want to use something like http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test your rules.

And there is also a whole lot of articles and resources on line explaining those concepts.